# How do we know radioactive decay can be modeled by the half-life equation, dq/dt = -aq?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I understand how to solve it. but **why** does

$$\frac{d \lambda}{dt} = -k \lambda$$

The equation, in and of itself, means the rate of decay is proportional to the amount at a given time. How do we know its not squared proportion, like universal gravitation? Or a squared/cubed relationship like Kepler's law that states the period squared is equal to the distance cubed.

Comment: Ultimately it's a good model because it accords with experimental evidence. (FYI, $d\lambda/dt$ isn't proportional to time, but the amount of remaining material $\lambda$.) Now you might ask why at a quantum level, it works. I.e., starting with some general physical principle, can you derive this result. That would be good question for Physics SE.

Comment: Okay thank you.  This always appears in applied diff eq models so I thought it would apply here. Also, I did say the rate of decay was proportional to the amount, the amount at a given time lol.  Anyways thanks for the quick response.  I guess it does require a deeper understanding of physics, which I lack (taking physic E&M next semester).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying assumption is that each atom's decay is treated as an independent event, and that the probability of it decaying in any given second is a constant.  (In other words, a Poisson process.)

So, the more atoms you have around to decay, the more decays per second you'll get.